# MySQL strip ' on where queries

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a large table which contains, or not, records that have ' tags like (martin's, lay's, martins, lays, so on).

Actually to search the client can be write exactly text, for example: martin's, to search all records that contains "martin's" but it is complicate, then, I need the client can to search by "martins" or "martin's".

**This is a simple example:**

*A mysql table like:*

```
ID |  Title 
---------------
1    lays
2    lay's
3    some text
4    other text
5    martin's
```

I need a sql query to search by `lays` or `lay's` and both need show me a Result like:

```
ID |  Title 
---------------
1    lays
2    lay's
```

I'm tried with many post solutions but I cant do that :-(

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To search if the word contains:

```
select t.*
from t
where replace(t.title, '''', '') LIKE '%lays%';
```

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the single quote:

```
select t.*
from t
where replace(t.title, '''', '') = 'lays';
```

Comment: Perfect, I'm only added on where `... LIKE '%lays%';` and work GOOD for me.

Comment: @JoseCarlosRamosCarmenates . . . Your question does not suggest that such wildcards are necessary.